# ScrollMagic: How to place content on top of parallax background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

So I am having an issue with building a vertical parallax scrolling website.

At the moment I am using `ScrollMagic` to create parallax sections, and it works perfectly. The issue comes when I try to put content on top of it. For my situation I am using `Bootstrap's` `.container` so I can put my content in different rows,columns and etc.

I can see the flaw, it is in the structure itself but I am trying to find a way how to hack it, any ideas?

```
<!-- Main Container -->
<div id="fullpage">
<div class="spacer s0"></div>
<!-- Section -->
<div class="section">
    <div class="absolute main-wrapper container">

        <div class="row">
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi amet asperiores, illo sapiente, magni fuga distinctio quisquam tenetur error natus accusantium cum veniam voluptatem! Id qui at quas culpa facere.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="parallax1" class="parallaxParent">
<div style="background-image: url(img/bcg_slide-1.jpg);">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /Section -->
<!-- Section -->
<div class="spacer s1">
<div class="box2 blue">
<p>Content 1</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /Section -->
<!-- Section -->
<div class="spacer s0"></div>
<div class="section">
<div id="parallax2" class="parallaxParent">
<div style="background-image: url(img/bcg_slide-2.jpg);"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /Section -->
<div class="spacer s1">
<div class="box2 blue">
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="spacer s0"></div>
<!-- Section -->
<div class="section">
<div id="parallax3" class="parallaxParent">
<div style="background-image: url(img/bcg_slide-3.jpg);"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /Section -->
</div>
```

So If I put my `div` before the background parallax image, It overlaps parallax image, and creates a white container with text. I have done `position absolute`, but that means I cannot use `bootstrap's grid`.

I tried putting inside the `div` with parallax background.

I am opened to ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually cracked it. It was much simpler than I thought.

In my code, I just declared a `<div>` with  `position: absolute;`, `width: 100%;` and `z-index: 1;` like this.

```
<div class="section">
  <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 1;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugiat officiis aspernatur deserunt molestias debitis placeat ratione fugit sed. Rem consectetur facilis maiores facere velit error eos quisquam dolorem aliquam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
                <div id="parallax2" class="parallaxParent">
                    <div style="background-image: url(img/parallax_bg2.png);"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

So this creates a `<div>` on top of my `<div>` with parallax image.
It has been tested on multiple sections and it works. Simple. duh...